# Multiple white space in html

Tags: html, styles, whitespace

I would like to ensure that my chords above words are separated nicely by multiple white space.

The issue is that when I use `pre`, it comes out pre-formatted and hence not what I wanted.

Also, with `&nbsp;`, the code looks very ugly.

What is the best method to solve this?

`<pre>Chorus:
          Em            A
A common love for each other
          F#m          Bm
A common gift to the Saviour
</pre>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Em &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;A &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; D &nbsp;   &nbsp; D7
A common bond holding us to the Lord`

Here is the link to the url: http://teach.sg/blog/a-common-love/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some white space characters like `&emsp;` will be useful. You can use `&#09;` for tab. You can also use CSS for this.

Comment: I see, what would I need to incorporate for CSS to allow for the multiple white spaces?

Comment: try something like style="padding-left:10px;"

Comment: I understand that padding left will help for the spacing of the first chord. But for the remaining chords, I'll then have to use &emsp;?

Comment: No. Place other chords in separate <div> tags and write css for them with padding-left.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative solution, please see if it is suitable for your purposes:

I have nested all chords in a `<span class = 'chord'>` element, and then used CSS style rules to move the chords up and to the left a little bit. There is a little bit of ugly whitespace with this method, but it is more concise and definitely much more elegant than spamming space characters.

```css
.chord {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  bottom: 1.5em;
  right: 2em;
  width: 0.5em;
}
p {
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>A common love <span class='chord'>Em</span> for each other <span class='chord'>A</span> 
  </p>
  <p>A common gift <span class='chord'>F#m</span> to the Saviour <span class='chord'>Bm</span> 
  </p>
  <p>A common bond <span class='chord'>Em</span> holding us <span class='chord'>A</span> to the Lord <span class='chord'>D-D7</span> 
  </p>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cmp5am06/).